# Does Epplus support set sheet data/cell value by office open xml?

Tags: c#, epplus

#### My question :

If there is a sheet data format with office open xml like below :

```xml
        <sheetData>
            <row r="1" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
                <c r="A1" t="s">
                    <v>0</v>
                </c>
                <c r="B1" t="s">
                    <v>1</v>
                </c>
                <c r="C1" t="s">
                    <v>2</v>
                </c>
            </row>
            <row r="2" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
                <c r="A2">
                    <v>1</v>
                </c>
                <c r="B2">
                    <v>2</v>
                </c>
                <c r="C2">
                    <v>3</v>
                </c>
            </row>
            <row r="3" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
                <c r="A3">
                    <v>4</v>
                </c>
                <c r="B3">
                    <v>5</v>
                </c>
                <c r="C3">
                    <v>6</v>
                </c>
            </row>
            <row r="4" spans="1:3" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
                <c r="A4">
                    <v>7</v>
                </c>
                <c r="B4">
                    <v>8</v>
                </c>
                <c r="C4">
                    <v>9</v>
                </c>
            </row>
        </sheetData>
```

how can I set this xml for epplus to change the cells value?

#### What I tried :

Searching epplus and only `Cells[IndexName].Value = "xx"` api.

#### What I expect for :

some epplus method like :

```
ws.SetSheetDataXml = xml;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get to and manipulate the XML for the `Worksheet` like this:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\SomeExcelFile.xlsx");

using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var workbook = pck.Workbook;
    var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
    var xdoc = ws.WorksheetXml;

    ...
}
```

Obviously, you will have to be careful what you do with it so Epplus does not get upset when you try to save it.  Generally, messing with the XML directly is a last resort for thing that Epplus cannot do.  Here are a few examples:

[How can I turn background error checking off for the Excel app object in EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334961/how-can-i-turn-background-error-checking-off-for-the-excel-app-object-in-epplus?noredirect=1#comment69898723_41334961)

[How to stop other conditional formatting from disappearing when hackmodding databars into solid fills?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417819/how-to-stop-other-conditional-formatting-from-disappearing-when-hackmodding-data)

[X-Axis label formatting issue while exporting Chart to Excel using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55743869/x-axis-label-formatting-issue-while-exporting-chart-to-excel-using-epplus#comment98253473_55743869)